# for in for loop (for's working in parallel)

Tags: python, python-3.x

If I wanted to write a program where it takes your schedule of week and assign it to a list

Schedule will include seven days a week and user enters what he has in his schedule

So my problem is : I'm using for in for loop to show the day and assign the data of schedule of user. In second for I cant assign data to each assignment and only 1 is assign

When I assign the data it only saves it in first list not other 6.

in this code schedule is a list that includes other 7 lists named from a to g like this: `schedule=[a,...,g]`. what should I do ?

```
for day in week:
    for data in schedule:
        while True:
            b = inputrange("Your schedule for  " + day + " ? "7)
            if b == 'done':
                break
            data . append (b)
        break
for data in schedule:
    print(data)
    print(40 * '='7):
```

it will like multi...table but what I want to assign each data to each day butis : only and only 0*0 and then 1*1 then 2*2 and so on I only this part of code not all of the data assigns to 1 day.

Comment: How do you initialize `schedule`?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Your description of the problem is not very clear, and the code that you posted lacks context (it refers to variables whose definitions are elsewhere in your code).

Comment: Try getting ride of the second brake.

Comment: Your edit has fundamentally altered your question. It is now about a different topic, and is less clear that it was before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you really need two for loops and one while loop.

refer to the code below:

```
schedule = []
week = ['sun','mon','tue','wed','thu','fri','sat']
for day in week:
    while True:
        b = input("Your schedule for  " + day + " ? ")
        if b == 'done':
            break
        schedule.append(b)

for data in schedule:
    print(data)
    print(40 * '=')
```

You should consider using a dictionary in the following structure to store the data accurately and present it in a pleasing manner later.

```
schedule = {
'Mon':['task1', 'task2', ....],
'Tue': ['task1', 'task2', 'task3', ....]
.
.
.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
for i in range(7):
    print(i, "*", i, " = ", i * i)
```

Prints:

```
0 * 0  =  0
1 * 1  =  1
2 * 2  =  4
3 * 3  =  9
4 * 4  =  16
5 * 5  =  25
6 * 6  =  36
```

Answer (score 0):

[This question has changed alot, so this answer references old material]

If you could post more information that would be great. Not sure what you mean by fors working in parallel. This is more like a [nested for loop](https://study.com/academy/lesson/nested-loops-in-python-definition-examples.html). Take a look at nested loops that might help.

But you have 3 loops within side each other. You probably only need to have 2 two and then can remove a few breaks. You need to loop through the days of the week and then to loop through the schedule.

Your code could look like this.

```
week = ["Mon","Tues","Wed","Thur","Fri"]
schedule = []#this is a 2 dimentional array. It shows the days and each event of per day

for day in week:
    #loop through each day of the week
    data = []
    while True:
        #ask for the schedule
        b = input("Your schedule for " + day + " ? ")
        if b == 'done':
            break#done
        data.append(b)
    schedule.append(data)#add to day

#print result
for data in schedule:
    print(data)
    print(40 * '=')
```

Comment: sir can you explain my problem

Comment: Why did the question change so much. I don't really understand your problem anymore

Comment: Maybe try opening a different question.

Comment: sorry about question editing so much it was my first time

Comment: No Problem. Here is some help on editing[link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit). Try going back to an older version of this question.